# zend framework 2 check if form valid just for one or two form items

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can i check in zend framework 2 if the submitted for is valid but jus for a specific item? insstead of

```
$form->insertData( $post ); 
if( $form->isValid() ) //dostuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a userfilter form which will contain your validators

For ex. if you want to make username field mandatory,then the validator in your userfilter form will be

```
$this->add(array(
                    'name' => 'username', 
                    'filters' => array( 
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'), 
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'), 
                    ), 
                    'validators' => 
                     array( 
                                      array(
                                       'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                                       'options' => array(
                                            'messages' => array(
                                         \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Username must be filled',
                                          ),
                                      ),
                                   ),
                                 ),

                          ));
```

Now in indexcontroller use this form to validate data as

```
$form->setInputFilter(new Userfilter($this->getServiceLocator()));
if( $form->isValid() )
'
'
'
```